# finding the closest Int value from a set of int values in objective c

Tags: objective-c, math, int

objective c math function question

I've got a x value that i'd like to compare to other values within a set, then determine which value from the set my x value is closest to.

For example, lets say i've got the ints 5, 10, 15, 20, 25.

What is the best way to determine which of these numbers is closest to 7?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How would you do this by hand? That being said, can you translate that into objective-c code?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please let us know so we can answer appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

```
    int closestDistance = INT32_MAX;
    int indexOfClosestDistance = -1;
    int x = 7;

    for (int i=0; i < [yourArray count]; i++)
    {
        int num = yourArray[i];
        int diff = abs(num - x);

        if (diff < closestDistance)
        {
            closestDistance = diff;
            indexOfClosestDistance = i ;
        }
    }
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Neither Objective-C nor Cocoa provides anything that solves this for you.  You can store your ints in a plain old array of `int`, or you can wrap each one in an `NSNumber` and store the wrappers in an `NSArray`.

If you're going to probe the array many times, sort it once in advance, and then for each probe use a binary search (standard C function `bsearch` or Core Foundation's `CFArrayBSearchValues` or Cocoa's `-[NSArray indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:]`) to find the nearest two elements.  If you're only going to probe the array once or twice, just use a for loop, subtraction, `abs`, and `MIN`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is subtract the smaller number from the larger one. So you'd want to compare the two numbers first, then just do simple subtraction. So you'd see the 10-7 is 3 away, and 7-5 is only 2 away.